# Allow users to send e-mails through a Rails app

Tags: email, ruby-on-rails-4, newsletter

I'm currently trying to make a Rails 4.1.1 app that allows users to send custom newsletters. I'd like to do this without asking for the user's mail account password if possible.

I just need it to appear as if the mail was sent from the specified e-mail address. Is this an unreasonable/impossible requirement? Is there any kind of service that can help me achieve it? Are there any common strategies for sending e-mail on a user's behalf?

Comment: You can set any `From:` header in your email, but most mail receivers will consider this as spam if the sender's domain does not fit the server it was sent from.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's not looking realistic without some big compromises. I'll have to rethink my approach.